# What are my options for motion control on the three consoles?

Tags: nintendo-wii, kinect, playstation-move

What are my options for motion control on the three consoles? What are the pros and cons of each motion control system on the Wii, Xbox 360, and Playstation 3?

Comment: I would edit the title to be less subjective, personally. Perhaps -- "What are my options for motion control on the three consoles?"

Comment: This feels a little vague. Do you think you could narrow down which pros and cons you're looking for?  For example: `Which of these systems has the largest dancing song collection` would be well defined.

Comment: Yes, you should.  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The real question you want to ask yourself is "what kind of games do I want to play." That question affects the "best" choice pretty heavily.

Hopefully, the below list will give a better overview to help your choice.

## The Nintendo Wii

- Largest current library
- cheapest standalone console
- You can acquire controllers (wii-motes) or even wii motion-plus versions packaged as parts of certain games.

## Playstation Move

- Most expensive controllers
- Most expensive console
- requires peripheral (Playstation Eye)
- Small game library, (some current playstation games getting retroactive support)

## Microsoft Kinect

- most expensive peripheral (the Kinect itself)
- excellent non-kinect 3rd party support (you may buy a kinect, but at the end of the day, you can fall back on Halo, if that's your kit)
- no extra costs in controllers
- small game library, few (none?) "hardcore" games with kinect support.
- [Milo was just plain creepy](http://www.gamesradar.com/xbox360/kinectimals/news/kinects-creepy-ass-milo-potentially-gets-sent-to-his-room-forever/a-20100923105513440014/g-2010061320911953067-).

Comment: I would add that you have a Blue-Ray player with a PS3.

Comment: first: halo is not a 3rd party game. it is a microsoft-owned IP published by microsoft games studios. second: if you're going to bring up third-party, ps3 has plenty of support (most major 3rd party games are released on both 360/ps3 nowadays), and the wii has pretty weak 3rd party support.

Comment: Don't forget about Zelda, reason enough to get a Wii.. for me it was a choice between PS3 and XBOX, having a Nintendo was a no brainer and kind of in a class of its own.

Comment: I don't really like the PS Move, it's executed pretty badly (THE EYE CAN'T SEE THE CONTROLLER! PANIC! PAUSE THE GAME!) and there were some bad design decisions IMO (try pressing start or select while holding the controller normally). That and the PS3 is the only console that loses features as it gets older.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, let me try this...

## **Nintendo Wii**

The Wii offers more family-friendly games, but has been around for a while to accumulate other types of games as well, with the largest game database of the three. Although, most people probably know a decent amount about it already, and this is the only one that I have.

### Pros

- Most games of the three with a good variety too.
- Cheapest
- Already has lots of third party support, as well as other addons from Nintendo(MotionPlus and Wii Fit Board)

### Cons

- Is still kind of lacking in content for hardcore gamers.

## **Playstation Move**

The move has a pretty good variety of games even though it's relatively new. A good article about it is [here](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/news/2010/09/playstation-move-1.ars/).

### Pros

- Good variety of games offering things for both casual and hardcore gamers.
- Has a pulsin' rubber ball on the top. :o
- Has a joystick as opposed to the Wii's d-pad.

### Cons

- Most expensive controllers. ($50 per controller, [$100 for all you'll need in addition to the PS3](http://www.gamestop.com/Catalog/ProductDetails.aspx?Product_ID=78137%28GameStopBase%29))
- Most expensive system.
- Less third party devices for it.
- Not that many games for it yet.
- Requires Playstation Eye.

## Microsoft Kinect

The Kinect stands out from the other two in that it doesn't have a physical controller, just a camera, and that has it's own pros and cons. So far, the Kinect has mostly [just dancing, fitness, racing, and sports games for it at the moment](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/news/2010/10/kinect-launch-titles-revealed-ms-hopes-you-like-dancing-fitness.ars), but there will probably be other things once people get more creative. [Here's another article](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/news/2010/08/why-sonys-move-offers-gamers-more-than-microsofts-kinectwhy-sonys-move-offers-gamers-more-than-microsofts-kinect.ars) comparing it to the Move and kind of to the Wii in the process as well.

### Pros

- No controller costs! :D
- Senses the whole body. (Although the Wii Fit has the Wii Fit Board which kind of makes up for this.)

### Cons

- Poor game selection both genre-wise and total amount.
- You can't control it in any way other then moving your body, which makes playing normal games with it impossible.
- The Kinect itself is most expensive. ([$150](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BSA298))

Comment: Don't forget that the Wii is currently at the end of its life span, with the announcement of the Wii U for 2012, so there will be few, if any, games, coming next year.

Comment: @Magnus: And the Xbox Next will be coming out the year after, and possibly the PS4 the year after that.